# Creating set of android input activities which only run at first run

Tags: android, android-activity

I am working on an android application. It has to take some information from the user only at the first run and then the app will use that information to work.

for ex - Suppose app has 5 activities, say Gender, Height, Weight, date of Birth, Name, which will be doing this job. So when the user first starts the app he enters this all info after that user will never see them.

I am stuck on this topic that how could i create them. 
Please answer precisely with source code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need an `Activity` for each information? You can create a single `Activity` with a lot of text boxes inside.

Comment: Have you resolved this yet?

Answer (score 0):

To check if data already exists, else ask questions:

```
String fileName = "UserData.txt";
String filepath = "MyFileStorage/StoredData";
try {   
 File myExternalFile = new File(cxt.getExternalFilesDir(filepath), filename);

 if(myExternalFile.exists()) {   
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myExternalFile);
  DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
  String strLine;
  while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
   myData = myData + strLine;
  }
  fis.close();
  br.close();
  in.close();
 }else{
 //must be first time so ask questions then save
 }
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

then if file dosnt exist, get the answers and write to file with;

```
String fileName = "UserData.txt";
String filepath = "MyFileStorage/StoredData";
File f= new File(cxt.getExternalFilesDir(filepath), fileName);
f.createNewFile();  
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(f); 
writer.append("Name"+System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Gender");
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

OR you could have a class called Globals, that extends Application;
put the variables to store in that class;

```
package ExamplePackage.YourPackage;

public class Globals  extends Application{
static String name="";
static int age = 0;

public Globals() {
    }
}
```

put an application tag in the androidmanifest;

```
 <application
    android:name=".Globals"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Comment: I will try to use this bit of code and then see if it works or not

Comment: Have a look at the part after 'OR', this is a way to globally store variables for use throughout the app lifecycle, and does not require a file. You could use the file to store the information and read it back when the app next starts.